# Spread operator is too slow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, optimization

How to increase the execution time of spread operator in JS? I need to add an object to an array of objects, but spread operator and push methods are to slow, because the data is too big. For example I have an array of objects like this and I need to add one/two/three/etc more objects to the array to update the state.

```
{
  "category": 64,
  "createdAt": "2023-06-06T09:12:34.997Z",
  "id": 297,
  "logo": "49.png",
  "name": "Center",
  "publishedAt": "2023-06-06T09:12:34.995Z",
  "subed": true,
  "table_name": "type",
  "updatedAt": "2023-06-06T09:12:34.997Z"
}
```

For now I'm doing it like that:

```
setState([...oldState, newItem])
```

But theres a visible delay between action (click f.e.) and the update of state

Comment: If it is too slow because of the size of the array, you must take a step back and look at the bigger picture. There probably is a better way to organise your data or different algorithm to use. What is the size of the array?

Comment: Are you sure it's the spread operator that is slow, and not the re-rendering of your components when the state updates? What exactly is "visible"?

Comment: @Bergi, clicking on a checkbox starts timer, updates seconds state and the state to show the timer. All timer logic is inside global context's useEffect and all state logic is handled by redux. When the showTimer state is true, only the animation starts, that moves timer to viewport, timer component itself is rendered but not visible. The state with array of objects fills with items that will be deleted when the timer runs out. Can it be context's useEffect that forces re-rerender?

Comment: How many of these items do you have? I doubt array operations are the problem unless there are tens of thousands of items.

Comment: Like @Bergi and @trincot already commented: it is _unlikely_ that the `...` operation is the actual culprit. However, your current code will create a new array instance each time it is executed and this might be noticeable if your array is very large. Using an `oldState.push(newItem)` would avoid this action and instead _append_ the new item to the already _existing_ array.

Answer (score -1):

```
setState(oldState.concat(newItem));
```

Comment: Please add more details to the answer or place this as a comment.